# Changing textures realtime in game engine

Tags: scripting, texturing, game-engine

I am looking for a way to change the texture in the game engine.
I have managed to apply 4 textures and enable/disable them usong a python script. The textures change is working, but only becomes visible when the BGE stops.
It seems that textures are not reloaded in realtime.
How can I force update the texture in realtime ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use texture bind ID.

Once you have it, you can pass a image buffer into it I think.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using functions from bpy? Don't use BPY in the game engine! Thankfully, bge.texture provides this functionality. Here's a code snippet that I use quite often:

```
def show_picture(obj, path, mat_id=0, tex_id=0):
    '''Loads a picture into a texture'''
    # The texture has to be stored in a place associated with other game data
    # so we store it in a game property. This name inlucdes the mat ID's and
    # tex ID's so that a single object with a complex setup does not have the
    # textures overwrite each other.
    # If a bge.texture object already exists for this object/mat_id/tex_id, then
    # we retrieve that.
    prop_name = 'SHOW_PICTURE{}:{}'.format(mat_id, tex_id)
    if prop_name not in obj:
        tex = bge.texture.Texture(obj, mat_id, tex_id)
        obj[prop_name] = tex
    else:
        tex = obj[prop_name]

    # Load the image from the path
    raw = bge.texture.ImageFFmpeg(os.path.join(path))

    # Check to see that it loaded
    if raw.status == bge.texture.SOURCE_ERROR:
        # Error in loading image
        raise ValueError("Unable to load image at {}".format(path))

    # Assign the new image to the texture and update the texture.
    tex.source = raw
    tex.refresh(True)
```

Pass in an object, a filepath and (optionally) the material slot and texture slot.

Now, this function reloads the image from disk every time you use it, and as a result it is quite slow - don't go calling it each frame. If you want to have something change picture rapidly, you need to keep it loaded in RAM and just point the plane's material at a bunch of different textures. This can be done by using the bind id. I don't have any nice code snippets for this, but maybe this line will help:

```
material = obj.meshes[0].materials[0]
material.textures[slot_id].bindCode = tex.bindId
```

where tex is some dynamic texture (ie a bge.texture.Texture object). You may be able to do:

```
material1.textures[slot_id].bindCode = material2.textures[slot_id].bindCode
```

But I have not tested that.

Comment: Hi, How does one find the material ID and texture ID?

Comment: Most objects have a single material, so most of the time you can leave it at zero. If not you can use: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bge.texture.html#bge.texture.materialID

It seems you use the same function for finding materials. Normally I just hard-code the values because they match the location in the material and texture slots. (ie a texture in the first texture slot has ID zero).

Comment: Thanks, I was actually able to find it out:     tex_id = bge.texture.materialID(obj, 'filename.jpg')